# Spring can't find bean and throws NoSuchBeanDefinitionException

Tags: java, spring, spring-bean

I have a problem with a realization of Spring in Action example of a programme.

Test class:

```
@Test
public void testBasicUsage() throws PerformanceException {
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/**/java/springidol/spring-idol.xml");
    Performer performer = (Performer) context.getBean("juggler");
    performer.perform();
}
```

Juggler class that should be configured by Spring

```
public class Juggler implements Performer {

    private int beanBags = 3;

    public Juggler() {
    }

    public Juggler(int beanBags) {
        this.beanBags = beanBags;
    }

    @Override
    public void perform() throws PerformanceException {
        System.out.println("JUGGLING " + beanBags + " BEANBAGS");
    }
}
```

And xml configuration file for this bean:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
    <bean id="juggler"
          class="springidol.Juggler">
        <constructor-arg value="15"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

this code throw NoSuchBeanDefinitionException:

```
Aug 30, 2018 1:20:43 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@1c53fd30: startup date [Thu Aug 30 13:20:43 EEST 2018]; root of context hierarchy

org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'juggler' available

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:686)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1210)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1089)
    at springidol.TestMain.testBasicUsage(TestMain.java:12)
```

[image]

Comment: are you sure your context.xml is being loaded?

Comment: Probably an error with the location of your spring context xml

Comment: Well its not a right way but try putting your context.xml file in src/main/java just to trouble shoot. and just put the name in ClassPathXml .

Comment: Can you show your project structure?

Comment: @codeLover add an image to description

Comment: You are using Maven non Java resources should Go in `src/main/resources` not in `Java`. Also the `Java` part isn’t part of the package.

Answer (score 0):

I think the class-path you provided in `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext`should be where the XML configuration in present. The files on classpaths are automatically scanned, we just need to provide folder paths.
Try below in Test class with changes:

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("java/springidol/spring-idol.xml");
```

Reference: [Spring Source](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.html)